# Help isolating "t" in this equation: $1.1 ^ t + 1.2 ^ t + 1.5 ^ t = 1,000,000,000$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

My math skills are a bit rusty :(

I'd like to isolate the exponent "t" in this equation.

$$
1.1 ^ t + 1.2 ^ t + 1.5 ^ t = 1,000,000,000
$$

So if I apply log on both sides, I'd have this:

$$
\log(1.1 ^ t + 1.2 ^ t + 1.5 ^ t) = \log(u)
$$

So is $$\log(1.1 ^ t + 1.2 ^ t + 1.5 ^ t)$$ equals to $$\log(1.1 ^ t) + \log(1.2 ^ t) + \log(1.5 ^ t)$$???

Thank you!

Comment: No! $\log (a+b) \neq \log a + \log b$ ! I don't really see any elementary way to actually isolate the $t$ here, and indeed there may not be a way to really do it.

Comment: Are you trying to solve for solutions for $u$ and $t$? Because as Osama said, isolating $t$ seems rather pointless here.

Comment: Trying to solve it for `t`, since `u` will be a known constant

Comment: You'll have to solve for $t$ numerically.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.1%5Et%2B1.2%5Et%2B1.5%5Et%3D10%5E9&t=crmtb01) gives $t=51.1098$

Answer (score 1):

### My feeling is that it's not solvable, analytically

This [list of logarithmic identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities) gives the identity $$\log\left(a_0 + a_1 + a_2\right) = \log a_0 + \log\left(1 + \frac{a_1}{a_0} + \frac{a_2}{a_0}\right).$$ Analytically, I think the best thing you'd be able to with that would be to write it as $\log(1 + x)$ and use taylor expansion, which would be very tedious, and would still not give you an exact answer.

My suggestion would be to use a numerical [root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithms)